# How to stop PacketCrypt ann on linux server using cli?

Tags: linux, docker, server, containers, mining

So I have a linux server, and suddenly I found the CPU usage goes up to 400% and when I looked at the tasks and services I found that there is a task called packetcrypt that is taking all my CPU and it is a docker container, so I want to uninstall it remotely using SSH

I tried `pkill` and `killall` `docker -remove` with no effect

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like your server has been hacked. PacketCrypt is a crypto mining algorithm so there is no reason why it should just "appear" on a server without you manually installing it.

I can't tell you how to fix the security breach because it depends on your specific setup, but I invite you to join the PKT Cash telegram chat, we can help you get your server secured and you can help us by providing information which we can use to track and slow down the hacker.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).